# Need a mysql query for sum each row with its previous row containing date and id

Tags: mysql

Need you help regarding mysql query.

Currently I have a table:

```
+--------------+-------------+----------------------+
|           Id | record_date | earnings             |
+--------------+-------------+----------------------+
|        20977 | 2019-11-22  |              -0.1737 |
|        20977 | 2019-11-23  |              -0.4867 |
|        20977 | 2019-11-24  |               1.3961 |
|        20977 | 2019-11-25  |              -1.0450 |
|        20977 | 2019-11-26  |               1.6639 |
+--------------+-------------+----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want result as addition on previous Id

```
+---------+-------------+----------------------+-------------+
|    Id   | record_date | earnings | sum_of_earnings per day                   |
+---------+-------------+----------------------+-------------+
|   20977 | 2019-11-22  |  -0.1737 |SUM(-0.1737)             |  
|   20977 | 2019-11-23  |  -0.4867 |SUM(-0.1737-0.4867)      |
|   20977 | 2019-11-24  |   1.3961 |SUM(-0.1737-0.4867+1.3961) |
|   20977 | 2019-11-25  |  -1.0450 |SUM(-0.1737-0.4867+1.3961+70.0000) 
|   20977 | 2019-11-26  |   1.6639 |SUM(-0.1737-0.4867+1.3961+70.0000+412.0000)
```

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly, But if I have multiple columns for summation then in that case above query will not going work.
Can you please provide the complete query if multiple columns need to sum up.
your help would be really helpful for me. Sorry, But i am new to database & mysql

Comment: Also want to add a point If month gets change then addition will from the 1st day of the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do a window sum:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(earnings) over(partition by Id order by record_date) sum_of_earnings_per_day
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, you could self-join the table and aggregate as follows:

```
select
    t.id,
    t.record_date,
    t.earnings,
    sum(t1.earnings) sum_of_earnings_per_day
from mytable t
inner join mytable t1
    on  t1.id = t.id
    and t1.record_date <= t.record_date
group by 
    t.id,
    t.record_date,
    t.earnings
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to calculate the sum for each day in a subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (select sum(earnings) from tablename where id = t.id and record_date <= t.record_date) sum_of_earnings_per_day
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sJyFFbYeQihPhK4SJvF5Zu/1).
Results:

```
| Id    | record_date         | earnings | sum_of_earnings_per_day |
| ----- | ------------------- | -------- | ----------------------- |
| 20977 | 2019-11-22 00:00:00 | -0.1737  | -0.1737                 |
| 20977 | 2019-11-23 00:00:00 | -0.4867  | -0.6604                 |
| 20977 | 2019-11-24 00:00:00 | 1.3961   | 0.7357                  |
| 20977 | 2019-11-25 00:00:00 | -1.045   | -0.3093                 |
| 20977 | 2019-11-26 00:00:00 | 1.6639   | 1.3546                  |
```

Answer (score 0):

even though we are not here to write queries for you.
modify this and it will give you what you need

```
SELECT
    trades.tx_date,
    trades.stock_code,
    trades.currency,
    trades.units,
    ( @sum := @sum + units ) AS unit_bal_total 
FROM
    trades
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @sum := 0 ) params 
ORDER BY
    trades.stock_code ASC,
    trades.tx_date ASC
```